# How to change BinWidth in histfit?

Tags: matlab, statistics, matlab-figure

How does one changes the bin width using histfit?

Or maybe, alternatively to use `histogram(x,'BinWidth',0.01)` and then draw a curve?

Comment: The width will be related to the number of bins right? change that

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. Not very elegant one, but it works:

```
    histogram(x,'BinWidth',0.1);
    h1=histfit(x);
    h1(1).Visible='off';
```